# Is there a way to display code coverage results metrix in ci-cd in github?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, code-coverage

I'm using code coverage tool in visual studio 2019 enterprise.

I get a .coverage file, but I want to display the matrix result in the CI.

Do you know any way to do that?

Thank you.

P.S

There is a GitHub action `danielpalme/ReportGenerator`
but it display results to a file. I need the same but display results in the CI-CD run itself.

Comment: Are you already using Github Actions?

Comment: Yes. I'm using GitHub actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what works for me:

```
 1. Using danielpalme/ReportGenerator action for generating csv file 
 2. Read the csv file to the ci-cd



  - name: Read Code Coverage
    id: covergae
    uses: juliangruber/read-file-action@v1
    with:
       path: Summary.csv
    
  - name: Echo Code Coverage
    run: echo "${{ steps.covergae.outputs.content }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a code-analysis service that is able to analyse your code-coverage reports generated by `dotnet test`, `ng test` or similar. For example [codecov.io](https://codecov.io)

- Go to [codecov.io](https://codecov.io)

  - Login with your account where your git repos are hosted (Github)
  - Click your avatar on the top right → Settings → Access
  - Generate token → name = GithubCI
  - Copy your token to a temporal notepad
- Go to your git repo that's hosted on hosting service ([github.com](https://github.com))

  - Settings tab → secrets
  - Add your codecov.io token here, either under repository secrets/organization secrets
- I then have the following github workflow (for angular) to run the unit tests, which generates the code coverage reports. The workflow then publishes the coverage reports to codecov.io
- 

```
name: npm-publish

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
  
    name: npm-publish
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    permissions: 
      contents: read
      packages: write 
    
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - name: Setup node
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: 14

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm install
    
    - name: Build
      run: npm run nx run-many -- --target=build --projects=ng-youtube-player-demo --configuration production --with-deps

    - name: Test
      run: npm run nx run-many -- --target=test --projects=ng-youtube-player-demo --with-deps  --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless --coverage --coverageReporters=lcovonly

    - name: Upload code coverage report
      uses: codecov/codecov-action@v1
      with:
        token: ${{ secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN }}
        directory: ./coverage/libs/mintplayer-ng-youtube-api
      
    - name: Upload code coverage report
      uses: codecov/codecov-action@v1
      with:
        token: ${{ secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN }}
        directory: ./coverage/libs/mintplayer-ng-youtube-player
      
    - name: Push to NPM
      uses: JS-DevTools/npm-publish@v1
      with:
        package: 'dist/libs/mintplayer-ng-youtube-api/package.json'
        registry: 'https://registry.npmjs.org'
        token: ${{ secrets.PUBLISH_NODE_TO_NPMJS_COM }}
        access: 'public'

    - name: Push to NPM
      uses: JS-DevTools/npm-publish@v1
      with:
        package: 'dist/libs/mintplayer-ng-youtube-player/package.json'
        registry: 'https://registry.npmjs.org'
        token: ${{ secrets.PUBLISH_NODE_TO_NPMJS_COM }}
        access: 'public'

    - name: Push to Github
      uses: JS-DevTools/npm-publish@v1
      with:
        package: 'dist/libs/mintplayer-ng-youtube-api/package.json'
        registry: 'https://npm.pkg.github.com'
        token: ${{ github.token }}
        access: 'public'

    - name: Push to Github
      uses: JS-DevTools/npm-publish@v1
      with:
        package: 'dist/libs/mintplayer-ng-youtube-player/package.json'
        registry: 'https://npm.pkg.github.com'
        token: ${{ github.token }}
        access: 'public'
```

`npm test` generates my code-coverage reports. The following step:

```
- name: Upload code coverage report
  uses: codecov/codecov-action@v1
  with:
    token: ${{ secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN }}
    directory: ./coverage/libs/mycompany-ng-youtube-player
```

uploads the coverage report to [codecov.io](https://codecov.io). They will then analyse your report, and when finished, you can put a badge on your readme.md

```
[![codecov](https://codecov.io/gh/MyCompany/mycompany-ng-youtube-player/branch/master/graph/badge.svg?token=K0B355423X3)](https://codecov.io/gh/MyCompany/mycompany-ng-youtube-player)
```

Find this badge markdown on [codecov.io](https://codecov.io) → your repository → Settings → Badge → copy the markdown

Comment: codecov.io. is a nice solution. though I can't use 'cause of security issues.

Comment: Is the code for commercial purposes? The code has to remain confined to your organization and cannot be exposed to third parties? Maybe, in case you're using Atlassian, or something similar, [they have a tool too](http://www.atlassian.com/software/clover). They even tried to document a [non-biased comparison of options per project-management system](https://confluence.atlassian.com/clover/comparison-of-code-coverage-tools-681706101.html)